# Nodejs libxmljs crashes docker container when xml fails schema validation

Tags: node.js, xml, docker, libxml-js

I'm making a web service in NodeJs that needs to support a specific xml request. So I'm using libxmljs to parse xml and validate it against an xsd.

On my Windows machine everything works well, so when doing this:

```
isValid = xml.validate(xsd)
```

isValid will be set as a boolean and xml will have items in the property validationErrors. Everything is fine until I run it in a docker container running node:10.15.2-alpine.

As long as the validation passes, everything is fine, but when there are validation errors, the entire docker container crashes.

I could not find an answer to this when googling so I will provide the answer myself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in your Dockerfile to use FROM node:10.15.2-slim and not FROM node:10.15.2-alpine.

Yes it uses more space, but the alpine edition is appearently not compatible with some of the prebuild python libraries the libxmljs uses.

Comment: Hi ,I am also facing same issue ,but my docker file complete different ,looks like 


FROM hub.docker.hpecorp.net/global-it/addison-nodejs:3.0.0


can you help me here? What I can change here?

Comment: No, I don't know about that, but if you found a solution, feel free to post it here :-)

Comment: I had the same issue and tried the node:10.15.2-slim image: got the very same /usr/src/app/node_modules/libxmljs/build/Release/xmljs.node: invalid ELF header  error message again.
I'll try with some other images and see if I can get passed that problem.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I was able to resolve it for some of the alpine distributions by installing python, g++ and make.

```
apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python && apk add --update --no-cache g++ && apk add --update --no-cache make
```